# Rails - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, sidekiq, airbrake

I am receiving NoMethodErrors when my DeltaSynWorker runs. This happens in an application that was built as a revision of a currently working application. I am not the original programmer, and I am coming at it from a Java background (I mention this because it is possible I am missing something very obvious to others). I cannot figure out why `NoMethodeError` is being thrown when the code is very similar to code that is currently working fine in a different web application.

**The Error:**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `client' for #<ApiRequestBuilder:0x0000000705a8f0>
```

**delta_sync_worker.rb**

```
class DeltaSyncWorker < SyncWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "delta_syncs"

  def perform(subscriber_id, client_id)

      sleep(10)
      current_subscriber = ApiSubscriberDecorator.decorate(Subscriber.find(subscriber_id))
      Time.zone = current_subscriber.time_zone
      client = ApiClientDecorator.decorate(Client.find(client_id))
      arb = ApiRequestBuilder.new(URI.parse(SR_HOST + '/servlet/sync/process'))

      if arb.client(:subscriber => current_subscriber, :client => client)

        arb.transmit

        if arb.success?
          current_subscriber.touch(:sync_updated_at)
          decorated_client = ClientDecorator.decorate(client.model)        
          ConfirmationsSyncWorker.perform_in(1.hours, current_subscriber.id)
        else
          error_params = {:subscriber => current_subscriber.id, :response_body =>            arb.response.body, :request_body => arb.request.body, :sync_type => "DeltaSyncWorker"}
          Airbrake.notify(:error_class => "sync_error", :error_message => "Sync Error: #{arb.response.message}", :params => error_params)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

**api_request_builder.rb**

```
require 'nokogiri'
class ApiRequestBuilder < AbstractController::Base
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include AbstractController::Layouts
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include AbstractController::Translation
  include AbstractController::AssetPaths

  self.view_paths = "app/api"

  attr_accessor :request_body, :request, :response, :append_request_headers, :request_method, :url

  def initialize(url, *args)
    @url = url
    if args
      args.each do |arg|
        arg.each_pair{ |k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k.to_s}", v) }
      end
    end
  end

  # this will search for an api request template in api/requests, render that template and set any instance variables
  def method_missing(meth, *args, &block)

    if lookup_context.template_exists?("requests/#{meth.to_s}")

      if args
        args.each do |arg|
          arg.each_pair{|k,v| instance_variable_set("@#{k.to_s}", v) }
        end
      end

      @request_body = (render :template => "requests/#{meth.to_s}")
    else
      super
    end

  end

  def transmit
    @request_method ||= "Post"
    @request = "Net::HTTP::#{@request_method}".constantize.new(@url.path)
    @request['x-ss-user'] = @subscriber.sr_user if @subscriber &&        @subscriber.sr_user.present?
    @request['x-ss-pwd'] =  @subscriber.sr_password if @subscriber && @subscriber.sr_password.present?

    unless @append_request_headers.nil?
      @append_request_headers.each_pair{ |k,v| @request[k] = v }
    end
    @request.body = @request_body if request_body? && @request.request_body_permitted?

    @http = Net::HTTP.new(@url.host, @url.port)
    @http.use_ssl = true
    @http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    @response = @http.request(@request)

  end

  def success?
    if @response.code == 200.to_s
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

  def request_body?
    unless @request_body.nil?
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

I have been looking at other `NoMethodError` questions here, but I cannot find an answer I feel applies to my situation. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`method_missing` will catch sent messages for which there is no method defined, and the call to `super` at the end will pass it up to Ruby's standard `method_missing` behavior, which is what you are seeing (`NoMethodError`). However, this only happens if the `if` condition is not met, which is what I suspect is happening here, and would explain why it works in some situations but not in others. The call to `:client`, having found no matching methods along the inheritance chain, will look for a template called "requests/client" - try adding this template and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Ok, I am following what you are saying. There exists both a "_client.xml.api" template and a "client.xml.api" template in the "api/requests/" path. Perhaps there is something wrong with the template itself?

Comment: Could be. I would try adding some `puts` statements inside `method_missing` so you can watch the flow control - i.e., `puts "template exists"` in the `if` statements, and `puts "template not found"` in `else`.

Answer (score 1):

I know Ive seen this before and I feel like it wasn't what it appeared to be, but ya basically method missing is just intercepting the method call and when you call arb.client, it is caught by method missing and therefore tries to render api/client.xml.arb or api whatever the file type is. -- Note that there should be a file in the initializers directory named somethig like api_template_handler.rb or arb_temmplate_handler.rb, which is what allows rails to see that template type in the view directory -- make sure that is there first. Also sidenote, _client.xml.api is a partial used by the other api request in that directory (full sync),

To debug Id start by, above the following line

```
if lookup_context.template_exists?("requests/#{meth.to_s}")
```

Add a log statement

```
Rails.logger.debug "Can I see View?" + lookup_context.template_exists?("requests/#{meth.to_s}")
```

If true, then the problem is the error isnt getting caught properly because of method missing. If false, then the sidekiq worker isnt loading rails properly, or the view path isn't being added onto the rails view paths.

If true, Im guessing it might have something to do with the client model not being loaded, or an attribute on the client model not existing, that the builder is trying to call, and the error is somehow bubbling up to the api request builder class.

Oh also, just general stuff, but make sure redis and sidekiq are running, and restart passenger if its non local environment.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Despite me adding that line (as well as putting similar log statements at different spots), I have not actually witnessed the output in the production.log.

I confirmed that redis and sidekiq are running, and I restarted passenger via: `touch /webapps/rackapp/tmp/restart.txt`

I can see the worker in Sidekiq attempt to process the job, but then fails and goes to the retries queue.

Comment: For what it is worth, I have also tried the following in the Rails console in production environment on the production server:  
`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console` then 
`include ActionView::LookupContext::ViewPaths` then 
`helper.lookup_context.template_exists?("requests/client.xml.api")`   
Which yielded:  
`=> false`